# Populate Ontology by converting huge xml file into rdf

Tags: xml, xslt, wiki, rdf, ontology

I try to populate an ontology with data extract from marvel database wikia (you can extract an xml that contains all informations of a wiki). My issue is that this xml is too heavy to do anything with it (more than 500Mo). I've try to transform it into much simple rdf file with xslt but because of the xml file size it's quite impossible.

The xml document is made of pages as this one:

```
<page>
<title>Aeroika (Earth-616)</title>
<ns>0</ns>
<id>1035</id>
  <sha1>11t0be5viqp0vsj8zwglfu3wea8fou4</sha1>
<revision>
  <id>1786343</id>
  <timestamp>2011-10-04T17:49:37Z</timestamp>
  <contributor>
    <username>HamsterMan</username>
    <id>2082346</id>
  </contributor>
  <minor/>
  <text xml:space="preserve" bytes="1652">{{Marvel Database:Character Template
| Image                   = Aeroika (Earth-616).jpg
| RealName                = Aeroika
| CurrentAlias            = Aeroika
| Aliases                 = 
| Identity                = 
| Affiliation             = [[Defenders (Earth-616)|Defenders]]
| Relatives               = 
| Universe                = Earth-616
| BaseOfOperations        = [[Tunnelworld]]

| Gender                  = Male
| Height                  = 
| Weight                  = 
| Eyes                    = 
| Hair                    = Gold
| UnusualSkinColour       = Gold
| UnusualFeatures         = Wings growing out of his head.
}}
[[Category:Flight]]</text>
</revision>
</page>
```

For exemple in this case I did a xslt that extract important datas in an rdf.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:si="http://www.w3schools.com/rdf/">

<xsl:for-each select="page">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(revision/text, 'Character Template')">
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="{title}">
                <Image><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Image'),'|'),'=')" /></Image>
                <RealName><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'RealName'),'|'),'=')" /></RealName>
                <CurrentAlias><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'CurrentAlias'),'|'),'=')" /></CurrentAlias>
                <Aliases><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Aliases'),'|'),'=')" /></Aliases>
                <Identity><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Identity'),'|'),'=')" /></Identity>
                <Affiliation><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Affiliation'),'|'),'=')" /></Affiliation>
                <Relatives><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Relatives'),'|'),'=')" /></Relatives>
                <Universe><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Universe'),'|'),'=')" /></Universe>
                <BaseOfOperations><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'BaseOfOperations'),'|'),'=')" /></BaseOfOperations>
                <Gender><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Gender'),'|'),'=')" /></Gender>
                <Height><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Height'),'|'),'=')" /></Height>
                <Weight><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Weight'),'|'),'=')" /></Weight>
                <Eyes><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Eyes'),'|'),'=')" /></Eyes>
                <Hair><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Hair'),'|'),'=')" /></Hair>
                <UnusualSkinColour><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'UnusualSkinColour'),'|'),'=')" /></UnusualSkinColour>
                <UnusualFeatures><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'UnusualFeatures'),'|'),'=')" /></UnusualFeatures>
                <Citizenship><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Citizenship'),'|'),'=')" /></Citizenship>
                <MaritalStatus><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'MaritalStatus'),'|'),'=')" /></MaritalStatus>
                <Occupation><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Occupation'),'|'),'=')" /></Occupation>
                <Education><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Education'),'|'),'=')" /></Education>
                <Origin><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Origin'),'|'),'=')" /></Origin>
                <PlaceOfBirth><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'PlaceOfBirth'),'|'),'=')" /></PlaceOfBirth>
                <Creators><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Creators'),'|'),'=')" /></Creators>
                <First><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'First'),'|'),'=')" /></First>
                <HistoryText><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'HistoryText'),'|'),'=')" /></HistoryText>
                <Powers><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Powers'),'|'),'=')" /></Powers>
                <Abilities><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Abilities'),'|'),'=')" /></Abilities>
                <Strength><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Strength'),'|'),'=')" /></Strength>
                <Weaknesses><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Weaknesses'),'|'),'=')" /></Weaknesses>
                <Equipement><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Equipement'),'|'),'=')" /></Equipement>
                <Transportation><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Transportation'),'|'),'=')" /></Transportation>      
                <Weapons><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(revision/text, 'Weapons'),'|'),'=')" /></Weapons>
            </rdf:Description>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</rdf:RDF>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do you have any idea of how can i do that ?
Thanks

Comment: This is an extremely broad question, do you have any examples of the specific XML format you're starting with and the kind of rdf structure you want to map it into? There's probably a streaming or "semi-streaming" approach you could use to read the XML but it really depends on the structure.

Comment: Thanks for indications. I've edit my question, i hope i didn't forget anything this time. You talk about streaming or semi-streaming approach, but i don't see how to do that in practice. Is it possible with xslt or do i have to make a program.

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? I mean, what does the final output/app look like in your mind? Start from there and go backward to what you have. I suspect that RDF is not really what you want, but you need to be a *lot* more specific. Once you do that the necessary transform will probably be fairly obvious and straightforward.

Comment: Ok, i'll be a lot more specific. I want to create an ontologie about comics (especially marvel) with Protege and I want to create individuals automatically that's why I've download the huge xml file on wikia (marvel comics database). In Protege you can import rdf/xml files to create automatically all individuals. The final aim is to querie the ontologie and to create different graphic presantions of the datas with xslt.

Comment: Apart from anything else, if your XML file is so big that you have memory problems when processing it, odds are that even if you manage to convert it to RDF, it will be too big for Protege to read and work with. You need to start looking at triplestore-based solutions I think.

Comment: Thanks you, but I thought of convert in rdf only a part of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSLT stylesheet transforms "normal" XML to RDF/XML syntax - which will be equally large or even larger, and almost as difficult to process. Moreover, RDF/XML is complex to write by hand, and easy to get wrong. Debugging your XSLT is going to be a nightmare.

If your goal is to make your dataset more compact and easier to process, I suggest that instead, you transform your XML to RDF [Turtle](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/) or RDF [N-Triples](https://www.w3.org/TR/n-triples/) syntax. These are extremely simple, compact text-based formats that lend themselves well to streaming processing, and any RDF-enabled software will be able to read and write these formats.

You can use XSLT, or if that gives you scalability issues use any programming/scripting language that has some basic XML support - get a streaming XML parser and hook in a simple script/program that processes parser output and creates RDF data on the fly. Or, given that your input XML is fairly regularly structured, you could even skip using an XML parser altogether and just hack together a couple of regular expressions to read data - whichever technology you're most comfortable with.

Of course, you can also try and use some of the end-user tools out there with built-in support for this kind of thing. For example, Topbraid Composer has some fancy features for this kind of conversion out of the box.